# Positioning Controls in the .Net GroupBox

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, controls, groupbox

Normally, I write forms that are resizeable (gracefully) using the method below.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace silly
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        private GroupBox g;
        private Button b1, b2;
        public Form1()
        {
            Init();
        }
        private void Init()
        {
            //create and add controls.
            this.Controls.Add(g = new GroupBox());
            g.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { 
                    b1 = new Button(),
                    b2 = new Button()});


            g.Text = "group";
            b1.Text = "b1";
            b2.Text = "b2!";


            b1.AutoSize = b2.AutoSize = true;


            g.Resize += new System.EventHandler(g_Resize);

        }

        private void g_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            b1.Size = b2.Size = new Size(g.ClientSize.Width, g.ClientSize.Height/2);
            b1.Location = Point.Empty;
            b2.Location = new Point(b1.Left, b1.Bottom);
        }
        protected override void OnResize(System.EventArgs e)
        {
            g.Size = this.ClientSize;
            g.Location = Point.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

However, you will quickly notice, that the `g.ClientSize` property doesn't work like the `Form.ClientSize` property. What I have been doing is adding a `Point` with the values:

```
private readonly static Point grp_zero = new Point(10, 20);
```

to help properly place components.  Using this value, I can refactor the `g_Resize` method with:

```
b1.Size = b2.Size = new Size(g.ClientSize.Width - grp_zero.X * 2, 
    g.ClientSize.Height/2 - grp_zero.X - grp_zero.Y);
b1.Location = grp_zero;
b2.Location = new Point(b1.Left, b1.Bottom);
```

with fairly good results.  However, if at the end of `Init();`, the following code is found:

```
            g.Font = new Font(g.Font.FontFamily, 28);
```

or something like it, `grp_zero` deserves to be resized.

**Question**

Is there a good workaround against this madness?  What do you do?

I tried `Dock` and `Anchor`, but I can't seem to get them to make the buttons fill up the `GroupBox` client area.  The effect I'm after here is for each button to fill his half of the client area.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was going to suggest Anchor and Dock. I can't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: As much as you don't LIKE them, they are there so you can do what you want to achieve.  You can either click your way through, or try to tear it apart with code. I prefer clicking.

Comment: What don't you like about `Anchor`?  Is it because you don't use the designer?

Comment: I don't use the designer.  I don't usually like WYSIWYG because, although in simple cases it can be very effective, complicated cases often become exponentially complicated.  To exert fine control over the layout, manual layout is the way, and by now, for me, typing out layout code is probably quite faster than using the designer, not to mention modifying layout code!!  I modified the question to allow for `Dock` and `Anchor` answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried `Dock` and `Anchor`, but I can't
>   seem to get them to make the buttons
>   fill up the `GroupBox` client area. The
>   effect I'm after here is for each
>   button to fill his half of the client
>   area.

1. Add a `TableLayoutPanel` to the `GroupBox`

   1. Set its `Dock` property to `Fill`
   2. Set its `RowCount = 2` and `ColumnCount = 1`
   3. Set the `RowStyles` to 50% fill for each row.  Done by default in the designer.
2. Add your two buttons to the `TableLayoutPanel`

   1. Set their `Dock` properties to `Fill`
3. Done!

I also suggest giving the designer another chance - it really is very good!

Comment: I really can't stand using the mouse: there's no way to speed it up! Also, using a for-profit IDE rubs me wrong :) Perhaps if the designer would allow a rich set of keyboard commands...

Answer (score 3):

If you still want to use manual layout code, use the `DisplayRectangle` property instead of `ClientRectangle`.  I prefer the `Layout` event over `Resize`, too.

```
private void g_Layout(object sender, System.LayoutEventArgs e)
{
    b1.Size = b2.Size = new Size(g.DisplayRectangle.Width, 
                                 g.DisplayRectangle.Height/2 - 1);

    b1.Location = new Point(g.DisplayRectangle.Left, 
                            g.DisplayRectangle.Top);

    b2.Location = new Point(g.DisplayRectangle.Left, 
                           g.DisplayRectangle.Top + g.DisplayRectangle.Height/2);
}
```

Note, however, that [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.displayrectangle.aspx) states:

> This API supports the .NET Framework
>   infrastructure and is not intended to
>   be used directly from your code.